# Uploading custom fonts on your website

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

Good day. I am creating a simple website that adds text to the canvas. But I want the user to upload their own custom fonts and use it in the site. How can do that? I have seen that before you can use the font you still need to be write it in css.

Answer (score 0):

This may point you in the right direction...

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Also remember that google fonts is a large fonts database to you can direct your users to...

www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp

If you mess around with this ^^^  than you may figure it out...

Remember though that many browsers allow you to turn off JavaScript...

Also there are ways to change css values with php...

The best thing to try is... assuming that the users font is in their fonts directory on their computer... you can direct the user to type in the exact name of the font and it SHOULD detect the font...

Just keep chugging on :D

Answer (score 0):

I've never heard or seen that done before, even as a feature request lol.

How about maybe letting the user choose their own Google web font, that way you at least know what all the choices are.

Then you could either hardcode the font styles for a few Google web fonts, or have your app created new CSS files based on what font they choose.

Good luck!

Comment: I already search it but cant find anything. I have this problem because this  app is for my friend who is a graphic artist and she was tasked to create her own fonts. So, for her convenience I want to add feature where she can easily add her created font without adding any code.